# Substring without the first n characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, substring

I'm developing a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure and I want to get the last characters of a `varchar(38)` column.

I know there will always be at least 18 characters and I don't know the exact length of the column, because it is variable.

I think I can get the length of the column and do a subtract to use `SUBSTRING`, but I can't do that because I'm doing this:

```
set @externalCodes = (
    select Serial, AggregationLevel
      from ExternalCode where ProductionOrderId = @productionOrderId
    for json path
```

I'm generating a JSON and I don't know how to get the length of each `Serial` column inside a select.

My question is: how can I get a substring from a string without the first 18 characters without knowing its length?

One solution could be:

```
SUBSTRING(Serial, 18, 38)
```

And it always return the substring from 18 to the end of the string even if the string doesn't have a length of 38.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use:

```
RIGHT(RTRIM(Serial),LEN(Serial)-18)
```

This gets the length of the field and subtracts 18 from it, leaving you with everything after the 18th character.

Answer (score 10):

Your `SUBSTRING` solution seems good enough, I am not sure why you would need to ask for anything more. I would only like to note that if you want to skip the first 18 characters, then you should specify 19 as the second argument for `SUBSTRING`, because in SQL the character positions in a string start from 1. So this makes perfect sense and should work well for you:

```
SUBSTRING(Serial, 19, 38)
```

If you specify 18, then you will be skipping 17 characters.

The solution using `RIGHT` and `LEN`, [suggested by George.Palacios](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44945/george-palacios) will work as well but the results of these two solutions might not be the same depending on whether `Serial` can have trailing spaces. The reason for the possible difference is that the `LEN` function ignores trailing spaces, while `RIGHT` does not, which means that for a string with trailing spaces the result will most likely not be what you would expect.

Let me demonstrate that using a simple example with a shorter string. Suppose the maximum length is 10, the number of characters to skip is 4, and the specific string is `'abcde  '`. (The quotation marks here are just string delimiters, for you to be able to see the trailing spaces.) If you do

```
SUBSTRING('abcde  ', 5, 10)
```

you will get `'e  '` as the result, because `SUBSTRING` will simply start cutting the string at the 5th character and include all the characters up to the end of the string.

In contrast, the `RIGHT`/`LEN` option

```
RIGHT('abcde  ', LEN('abcde  ') - 4)
```

will yield `' '`. The `LEN` function will ignore the two trailing spaces and return 5. Subtracting 4 from 5 gives you 1, thus `RIGHT` will return just one rightmost character of the string, which is a space.

As I said, though, if `Serial` can never have trailing spaces, either option will do. For completeness, let me suggest one more, which uses the `STUFF` function:

```
STUFF(Serial, 1, 18, '')
```

The `STUFF` function allows you to delete a substring from and/or insert another one to a given string at a given position. So, in order to skip 18 characters using this function, you specify starting position 1, 18 characters to delete, and an empty string (`''`) to replace them with. Like `SUBSTRING`, this solution will correctly work with trailing spaces, should you have the need to take them into account.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why go through the extra step of getting the length when it is irrelevant. I haven't profiled it, but I suspect that this approach is slightly faster, even if minimally. But even if the same efficiency, it's more readable / cleaner code.